# Google Maps Zoom Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I am trying to use Google Maps using html and jQuery, but the zoom feature is not working, i'm trying to use this Google Maps with owntracks data check my code below.

```js
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDXNCKw3k07Z0QLw2GOuPjajvS0psHVCX0&libraries=places,drawing,geometry"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Google Maps JavaScript API:
    // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/?hl=de
    // Marker Icons:
    // https://sites.google.com/site/gmapsdevelopment/
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // JQuery
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

   var map = null;
    //make an empty bounds variable
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // LatLng's we want to show
   $( document ).ready($(function() {
    var mapOptions = {  
         zoom      : 13,
      }
      
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
     // ******************************************************************************
     $.ajax({
       url     : "../rest/items/locationIrvan/state/",
       data    : {},
       success : function( data ) {
        if ( map == null) { return; }
        if ( data == "Uninitialized") { return; }
        
        var coords = data.split(',');
        var latlngPatrik = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0],coords[1]);
        
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position  : latlngPatrik,
       map       : map,
       icon      : 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/pink-dot.png',
       title     : "Irvan"
        }) // end of [Marker]
          bounds.extend(latlngPatrik);
      } // end of [function]
     }) // end of [$.ajax]
  }))

    $( document ).ready($(function() {
    // ******************************************************************************
   // ******************************************************************************
     $.ajax({
       url     : "../rest/items/locationIrvan/state/",
       data    : {},
       success : function( data ) {
        if ( map == null) { return; }
        if ( data == "Uninitialized") { return; }

        var coords = data.split(',');
        var latlngKarin = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0],coords[1]);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position  : latlngKarin,
       map       : map,
       icon      : 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
       title     : "Irvan"
        }) // end of [Marker]

        $.ajax({
       url     : "../rest/items/mqttIrvanAccuracy/state/",
       data    : {},
       success : function( data ) {
       if ( data == "Uninitialized") { return; }
         var accuracy = parseInt(data);
         var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center        : latlngKarin,
        radius        : accuracy,
        map           : map,
        strokeColor   : '#00FF00',
        strokeOpacity : 0.8,
        strokeWeight  : 2,
        fillColor     : '#00FF00',
        fillOpacity   : 0.35,
         }); // end of [Circle]

         bounds.extend(latlngKarin);
         map.fitBounds(bounds);
       } // end of [function]
        }) // end of [$.ajax]
      } // end of [function]
     }) // end of [$.ajax]
       // map.fitBounds(bounds);
   }))
   </script>
```

```css
.Flexible-container {
     position: relative;
     padding-bottom: 0px;
     padding-top   : 0px;
     height        : 340px ;
     overflow: hidden;
   }

   .Flexible-container iframe,
   .Flexible-container object,
   .Flexible-container embed {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" class="Flexible-container" />
```

Whatever i change the zoom value, the result is just the same, i hope someone can give me a clue, i'm working this for a weeks but nothing, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using fit bounds. This is to adjust the zoom level to include all the marker. so whatever changes you changes to zoom level, it appear same.

Comment: comment the line "map.fitBounds(bounds);" and change zoom level

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'zoom' of null
    at Object.jb (map.js:14)
    at HTMLDivElement.C._.Yn.Oa (common.js:76)
jb @ map.js:14
C._.Yn.Oa @ common.js:76`

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
    var mapOptions = {  
                                zoom      : 13,
                                zoomControl: true
                        }
```